# How to stretch a grid item while leaving other items at auto height/width

Tags: css, css-grid

In a grid with two items, if I want the first item to be 50px and the second item to expand the full height, I can do this:

```css
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-rows: 50px; }
.item1 {}
.item2 {}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
</div>
```

However, if the content inside `.item1` grows beyond 50px, how do I get the first row to expand?

I've tried a few different solutions, including `minmax` and using `align-self` to try to stretch item1 when needed, but it feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Here's a starter fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mehulkar/d8f25L0g/

Note, that if possible I would like to NOT have to add additional classes to change the grid configuration when the content grows.

Comment: I'm not on a computer to verify this, but I think `grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, min-content)` should work? Reference: [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax).

Comment: @DavidThomas no :( I tried this, but `auto` divides all space evenly to `item1` and `item2`, so they both become 50% height, even when the content has not expanded.

Comment: auto and min-height works too https://jsfiddle.net/d8f25L0g/7/ but looks more like a typical flex grid https://jsfiddle.net/d8f25L0g/6/ or not

Comment: @DavidThomas `min-content` keyword worked, but I don't really understand what the docs mean! @Michael_B's solution also worked though. Not sure which answer to pick if you were to add this as an answer.

Comment: Michael took the time to post an answer, along with full code and a demo; I posted a comment. I won't say that you should accept his answer, you may in fact benefit from leaving the question 'open' (by not accepting an answer) for a day or so, to encourage others to post alternate answers that may also solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the first row to be at least 50px tall.

Tell the second row to consume remaining space in the container.

This should be all you need:

```
grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;
```

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#expand');

let longString = 'item1 should expand. ';
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  longString += longString;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const item1 = document.querySelector('.item1');
  if (button.innerText.match(/expand/i)) {
    item1.innerHTML = longString;
    button.innerText = "Collapse";
  } else {
    item1.innerHTML = "1";
    button.innerText = "Expand";
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, auto) 1fr;
}

.grid > div {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
Try:
<button id="expand">Expand</button>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1 y">1</div>
  <div class="item2 r">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any thoughts on using `minmax(50px, min-content)` instead? (As @DavidThomas pointed out in the comments) That also works, in addition to your solution here.

Comment: `auto` sizes the track based on content length. `min-content` sizes the track based on a "shrink-to-fit" algorithm. Personally, I don't see the difference. The spec doesn't clearly define `min-content` IMO. In fact, it says this about `min-content`: ["This specification does not define how to determine these sizes"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#intrinsic).

Comment: When dealing with competing solutions that do the same thing, I always prefer the simpler one (Occam's Razor). So I would just stick with `auto`.